# Passing JSON to web method and am getting error.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a *JSON* object that I need to pass from the server to the client side to save the data off in a database.

I can sucessfully pass it using:

```
var str2 = JSON.stringify({
    o: oJSON
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebForm1.aspx/Test",
    data: str2,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {},
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

and

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(),               
System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()> _
Public Shared Function Test(ByVal o As RootObject) As String
    Dim strName as string = textboxName.text
End Function
```

I have to save two different sets of data off. The first set has to be saved before the json object can be saved. It is justing saving textbox values to the database. The second set is storing the json to the database.

I am trying to set `sName` to equal the textbox value and am getting the following error:

> Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared
>   method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of
>   the class

Is there another way to pass the *JSON* object to the client side where I can access the textbox values on the page ?
Or am I going to have to include `Name` along with the other values that I need in the *JSON* object ?

Comment: You said you want to go "Server -> Page -> Database".  That doesn't sound right, don't you want to go "Page -> Server -> Database" ?  If this is what you want to do via Ajax using JSON, then you'll need a method that takes 2 values (example: beforeValue and afterValue).  Since you want to send the before/after values at the same time, you'll need to store the before value somewhere it doesn't change (like a hidden fields, JS varible, etc...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [you won't be able to access your Page's TextBox controls from the static/Shared method](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/). In order for them to have access to that, the AJAX call would have needed to pass the entire ViewState back and run the Page through its life cycle in order to instantiate the TextBox and determine what its value should be. At that point, you'd basically have the UpdatePanel, and would have lost the performance advantages of using page methods.